# Can't figure out how to make my collapsible navbar button not always visible (Bootstrap v.3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot figure out how to get my button for my collapsible navbar not to appear all the time. I have followed various online tutorials with almost the exact same code as mine however I am not achieving the same result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pentakill - About</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/pentakilllogo.ico">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metal Mania' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myCollapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar metal">Options</span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand pentaicon"><img src="images/pentakilllogo.ico"></a>
        <span class="navbar-brand metal">Pentakill</span>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myCollapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a class="metal" href="index.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="metal" href="about.php">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="metal" href="music.php">Music</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <a class="metal" href="tour.php">Tour</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="metal" href="members.php">Members</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="metal" href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Login/Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I have tried adding and removing various divs but nothing seems to make a difference.
I also tried removing the word "Options" in case that was the culprit, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intentionally using the Bootstrap 3.4 CDN instead of the most recent version? Following along on a tutorial such as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ may cause issues. I placed your code into a codepen linked to the latest version and don't see the button, just spacing issues then.